# Should we adjust for this variable?

Tags: causality, mediation, dag, adjustment, collider

Four variables $X$, $Y$, $A$, and $B$ are assumed to have relationships as in the following diagram:

[image]

Here, $X$ is the predictor and $Y$ is the outcome variable.

Suppose that the research interest is the **direct** (not total) effect between $X$ and $Y$. On the one hand, $A$ acts as a mediator along an open causal path, $X \rightarrow A \rightarrow Y$, and should be adjusted for in the model. On the other hand, $A$ plays the role of a collider in a separate noncausal, closed path, $X \rightarrow A \leftarrow B \rightarrow Y$, and should not be adjusted.

My confusion is: should we adjust for $A$ or not?

Comment: You shouldn't adjust for A or B. Neither of them meets criteria for collider, but both meet criteria for mediator.

Comment: @AdamO Just to clarify, my interest lies in the **direct** (not total) effect between X and Y. Do you mind elaborating the criteria for a collider and a mediator in this context?

Comment: Sorry, if direct (and not total) effect is of interest, only adjust for A. Even though B is conditionally independent of X after adjustment for A, you may choose to further adjust for B to reduce residual standard error

Comment: @AdamO Would you be able to elaborate on your comment and provide a former answer, including the reasoning behind it? Thank you!

Answer (score 4, accepted):

In order to get the direct effect, you must adjust for $A$. The direct effect is defined by adjusting for $A$. You have no choice but to adjust for $A$. To do otherwise would be to estimate a total effect, not a direct effect.

It should also be clear that you need to adjust for $B$. $B$ is a confounder of $A$ and $Y$, which means it is necessary to estimate the causal effect of $A$ on $Y$, which is necessary to identify the direct effect of $X$. As you noted, $B$ is also part of the collider path induced by adjusting for $A$. Controlling for $B$ blocks this path.

Note that the follow two explanations are isomorphic and describe the same bias:

1. $A$ is a collider on a noncasual path from $X$ to $Y$ (through $B$)
2. The relationship between $A$ and $Y$ is confounded by $B$

That is, the bias due to confounding is the same as the bias due to conditioning on a collider. The problem isn't adjusting for a post-treatment variable; all that does is change the interpretation of the effect of $X$ on $Y$ to be a direct effect rather than a total effect. The problem is that the $A\rightarrow Y$ relationship is confounded, which means the indirect effect is biased. Because the direct effect is a function of the (unbiased) total effect and the (biased) indirect effect, it is also biased.

All this is to say that you don't even need to concept of colliders to understand why any effect would be biased here. Simply understanding that $A \rightarrow Y$ is confounded, $A\rightarrow Y$ is a component of the indirect effect, and the direct effect is a function of the indirect and total effects (i.e., basic causality and mediation concepts) is sufficient to describe which variables should and shouldn't be controlled for and the consequences of controlling or failing to control for them.